# Yii2 - Assign method Url::to into a variable

Tags: php, yii2

Is it possible to pass an url to a variable ?

```
class ReportRequestController extends \yii\web\Controller{

   private $img = Url::to('@web/img/logo.png');

}
```

I got an error syntax :

```
syntax error, unexpected '(', expecting ',' or ';'
```

All of my code is work, just on this line. To prove it, I commented it.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-base-object.html#init()-detail

```
class ReportRequestController extends \yii\web\Controller {

    private $img;

    public function init()
    {
        parent::init();

        $this->img = Url::to('@web/img/logo.png');
    }
}
```